# Fixture scope doesn't work when parametrized tests use parametrized fixtures

Tags: python, pytest

I want to share fixtures between different instantiations of the same parametrized tests, where the fixtures themselves are also parametrized:

```py
#!/usr/bin/py.test -sv

import pytest

numbers_for_fixture = [0]

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if "config_field" in metafunc.fixturenames:
        metafunc.parametrize("config_field", [1], scope='session')

@pytest.fixture(scope = 'session')
def fixture_1(config_field):
    numbers_for_fixture[0] += 1
    return '\tfixture_1(%s)' % numbers_for_fixture[0]

@pytest.fixture(scope = 'session')
def fixture_2():
    numbers_for_fixture[0] += 1
    return '\tfixture_2(%s)' % numbers_for_fixture[0]

def test_a(fixture_1):
    print('\ttest_a:', fixture_1)

def test_b(fixture_1):
    print('\ttest_b:', fixture_1)

@pytest.mark.parametrize('i', range(3))
def test_c(fixture_1, i):
    print('\ttest_c[%s]:' % i, fixture_1)

@pytest.mark.parametrize('i', range(3))
def test_d(fixture_2, i):
    print('\ttest_d[%s]:' % i, fixture_2)
```

I get this output:

```
platform linux -- Python 3.4.1 -- py-1.4.26 -- pytest-2.6.4 -- /usr/bin/python
collecting ... collected 8 items

test.py::test_a[1]      test_a:     fixture_1(1)
PASSED
test.py::test_b[1]      test_b:     fixture_1(1)
PASSED
test.py::test_c[1-0]    test_c[0]:  fixture_1(1)
PASSED
test.py::test_c[1-1]    test_c[1]:  fixture_1(2)
PASSED
test.py::test_c[1-2]    test_c[2]:  fixture_1(3)
PASSED
test.py::test_d[0]      test_d[0]:  fixture_2(4)
PASSED
test.py::test_d[1]      test_d[1]:  fixture_2(4)
PASSED
test.py::test_d[2]      test_d[2]:  fixture_2(4)
PASSED
```

`test_a`, `test_b` and `test_c[0]` all share `fixture_1(1)`. All the `test_d`s share `fixture_2(4)`. The problem is that the `test_c`s use different versions of `fixture_1`.

This also happens when scopes are set to "module" and "class", and it only happens when both the test and the fixture are parametrized.

From the way pytest prints the test parametesr, it seems like it doesn't distinguish between the different types of parameters used for each item, so it creates a fixture for each set of parameters rather then for each unique subset of a parameters list that the fixture uses.

Is this a bug in pytest, or did I neglect to set some configuration or something? Is there a workaround?

Comment: It seems to be a reported bug - https://bitbucket.org/hpk42/pytest/issue/634/metafuncparametrize-overwrites-scope

Comment: updated link https://bitbucket.org/pytest-dev/pytest/issue/634/metafuncparametrize-overwrites-scope

Comment: This issue is not completely solved. See the related issue https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/1697

Comment: Take a look in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37351349/returning-multiple-objects-from-py-test-fixture/37351707#37351707) might help you.

Answer (score 2):

In a nut shell, there's a bug where the scoping is effectively ignored in this case. Run pytest with the --setup-show switch to get a better view of when the fixtures are set up and torn down.

### Workaround

Comment out the pytest_generate_tests function and add the following:

```
@pytest.fixture('session', [1])
def config_field(request):
    return request.param
```

Now you should see the correct set up and tear down nesting.

### Workaround for dynamic parameters

I needed to set my parameters from a cli agument and had to use pytest_generate_tests

Set indirect to True and paramters to the cli argument:

```
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if "config_field" in metafunc.fixturenames:
        metafunc.parametrize(
            "config_field",
            metafunc.config.getoption('some_option'),
            True,
            'session'
        )
```

Add a place holder fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture('session')
def config_field(request):
    return request.param
```

Comment: I couldn't make this workaround for dynamic parameters work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, You can return yield from your feature, this might return the same value:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope = 'session')
def fixture_1(config_field):
   .. yield <fixture-properties>
```